# Invalid group by expression error when using any_value with max and window function in Snowflake

Tags: sql, group-by, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I was given a query and I am attempting to modify it in order to get the most recent version of each COMP_ID. The original query:

```
SELECT 
    ANY_VALUE(DATA_INDEX)::string AS DATA_INDEX, 
    COMP_ID::string AS COMP_ID, 
    ANY_VALUE(ACCOUNT_ID)::string AS ACCOUNT_ID, 
    ANY_VALUE(COMP_VERSION)::string AS COMP_VERSION, 
    ANY_VALUE(NAME)::string AS NAME, 
    ANY_VALUE(DESCRIPTION)::string AS DESCRIPTION,
    MAX(OBJECT_DICT:"startshape-type")[0]::string AS STARTSHAPE_TYPE,
    MAX(OBJECT_DICT:"startshape-connector-type")[0]::string AS STARTSHAPE_CONNECTOR_TYPE ,
    MAX(OBJECT_DICT:"startshape-action-type")[0]::string AS STATSHAPE_ACTION_TYPE,
    MAX(OBJECT_DICT:"overrides-enabled")[0]::string AS OVERRIDES_ENABLED
FROM COMP_DATA
GROUP BY COMP_ID
ORDER BY COMP_ID;
```

I then attempted to use a window function to grab only the highest version for each comp_id.
This is the modified query:

```
SELECT 
    ANY_VALUE(DATA_INDEX)::string AS DATA_INDEX, 
    COMP_ID::string AS COMP_ID, 
    ANY_VALUE(ACCOUNT_ID)::string AS ACCOUNT_ID, 
    ANY_VALUE(COMP_VERSION)::string AS COMP_VERSION, 
    ANY_VALUE(NAME)::string AS NAME, 
    ANY_VALUE(DESCRIPTION)::string AS DESCRIPTION,
    MAX(OBJECT_DICT:"startshape-type")[0]::string AS STARTSHAPE_TYPE,
    MAX(OBJECT_DICT:"startshape-connector-type")[0]::string AS STARTSHAPE_CONNECTOR_TYPE ,
    MAX(OBJECT_DICT:"startshape-action-type")[0]::string AS STATSHAPE_ACTION_TYPE,
    MAX(OBJECT_DICT:"overrides-enabled")[0]::string AS OVERRIDES_ENABLED,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COMP_ID ORDER BY COMP_VERSION DESC) AS ROW_NUM
FROM COMP_DATA
QUALIFY 1 = ROW_NUM;
```

When attempting to compile the below error is given:

> SQL compilation error: [COMP_DATA.COMP_ID] is not a valid group by expression

I had originally thought the issue was the ANY_VALUE on COMP_VERSION, but after removing the ANY_VALUE the same error was given. The only way I found to not get an error was removing the 4 MAX fields and all of the ANY_VALUE()'s, as shown below:

```
SELECT 
    DATA_INDEX::string AS DATA_INDEX, 
    COMP_ID::string AS COMP_ID, 
    ACCOUNT_ID::string AS ACCOUNT_ID, 
    COMP_VERSION::string AS COMP_VERSION, 
    NAME::string AS NAME, 
    DESCRIPTION::string AS DESCRIPTION,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COMP_ID ORDER BY COMP_VERSION DESC) AS ROW_NUM
FROM COMP_DATA
QUALIFY 1 = ROW_NUM;
```

Of course this is not at all sufficient since I need the 4 max fields.

I have also tried creating the table with the max fields and from that new table using the window function to select the highest COMP_VERSION of each COMP_ID, but the same error was given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you added your QUALIFY clause you dropped the GROUP BY clause from your SQL, aggregate function like MAX, need all selections to be aggregate function OR to have a GROUP BY clause.

So if you only want the best row per the grouping clause, which you note, you aggregate functions need to be explicitly windowed. Thus

```
SELECT 
    data_index::string AS data_index, 
    comp_id::string AS comp_id, 
    account_id::string AS account_id, 
    comp_version::string AS comp_version, 
    name::string AS name, 
    description::string AS description,
    MAX(object_dict:"startshape-type")OVER(PARTITION BY comp_id)[0]::string  AS startshape_type,
    MAX(object_dict:"startshape-connector-type")OVER (PARTITION BY comp_id)[0]::string AS startshape_connector_type ,
    MAX(object_dict:"startshape-action-type")OVER (PARTITION BY comp_id)[0]::string AS statshape_action_type,
    MAX(object_dict:"overrides-enabled")OVER(PARTITION BY comp_id)[0]::string AS overrides_enabled,
FROM COMP_DATA
QUALIFY 1 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY comp_id ORDER BY comp_version DESC);
```

There is a small chance you will need to add a set of brackets around those MAX's like

```
(MAX(object_dict:"overrides-enabled")OVER(PARTITION BY comp_id))[0]::string AS overrides_enabled,
```

But I suspect it will work out of the box. And I assumed you don't want the row_number so pushed it into the qualify (because it will always be the value 1)